# Problems with Installing Nobara along with Windows 10

Tags: linux, dual-boot, grub

I already have a Windows 10 Pro installed and want to install Nobara in a dual boot such that I can access either whenever I want to.

I downloaded the "Nobara-39-Official-2024-01-24.iso" from [here](https://nobaraproject.org/download-nobara/).

Then I got my USB drive and got the .iso file onto it using Rufus using the following settings(once with each) :

[image: a1]
[image: a2]

I already shrinked 75GB off my D drive and it is empty for Nobara to be installed.

Now each time I select any of the options in the screen that pops up with either of these(GPT or MBR), I am getting the following error :

```
error: ../../grub-core/fs/fshelp.c:257:file '/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz' not found.
error: ../../grub-core/loader/i386/efi/linux.c:258:you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

I am doing this on my laptop which is a Asus TP500LB with a i5-5200U, Nvidia GeForce 940M, 4GB RAM, 512GB SSD.

I can provide specific details if you require those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to go to your bios, then disable secure boot, if for some reason you still need it, you will need to install sbctl `dnf copr enable chenxiaolong/sbctl` `dnf install sbctl` then follow the [upstream instructions](https://github.com/Foxboron/sbctl?tab=readme-ov-file#key-creation-and-enrollment) to enable it, then re enable it in your bios.

Consider using ventoy instead with ventoy, you don't need to format the disk over and over, you just need to copy the ISO files to the USB drive and boot them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with ventoy. my secure boot is already disabled.

Comment: can you try a fedora iso to see if that works @DevNotTaken

Comment: also is tpm/fastboot enabled, if so, disable it

Comment: Using Ventoy fixed the issue and I was able to install Nobara onto the partition. But now, I am not able to boot into Nobara as the Grub bootloader isn't showing and my laptop directly boots into windows 10. I will however make another question for that issue. Thanks.